How to Enable HTTP/3 with Nginx from Ondřej’s PPA on Ubuntu 24.04?
I’m running Ubuntu 24.04 and using the Nginx packages maintained by Ondřej Surý (from ppa:ondrej/nginx). My Nginx version is 1.26.2, and I want to enable HTTP/3 (QUIC) support. I noticed that --with-quiche isn’t included in the default build configuration. Do I need to rebuild Nginx with --with-quiche manually, or is there another way to enable HTTP/3 with this precompiled version? Any guidance on the best approach would be appreciated!

Update:

Build Configuration: From my investigation, it seems that Nginx in this package is actually configured with --with-http_v3_module. This is somewhat confusing because this module typically indicates support for HTTP/3.
No Error Messages: I’ve successfully used HTTP/3-specific directives in my configuration (e.g., http3 on, listen 443 quic reuseport, and quic_retry on), and Nginx accepts them without throwing any errors. This suggests that some level of support for HTTP/3 might indeed be present.

Given these factors, I’m wondering if there might be something else going on under the hood. Could it be that the QUIC library is not fully integrated, even though the module is included? Or is there a different way to fully enable HTTP/3 support without recompiling Nginx? Any further insights or experiences with similar setups would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks again for your help!

If you read the title of the PPA, it says this: "PPA for NGINX Stable with HTTP/2".  It does not include HTTP/3 QUIC support.
Unless you build the package yourself with the HTTP/3 options specified in it, and then install it, you will not be able to get HTTP/3 support.  It is not compiled or built in Ondrej's packages nor the current (stable / non-development) Ubuntu release package versions of NGINX at this time.
If you want HTTP/3 options and support, you'll have to recompile the software and package with that option added.

Thank you for your response! I appreciate the clarification regarding the PPA and the absence of HTTP/3 QUIC support in the precompiled packages. However, I’d like to mention a few points that make the situation a bit more complex. Please see the update to my question.

@ekadagami i'm confused then, are you trying to use basic HTTP/3 or are you attempting something else?  At this point you'll need to do debugging on your installation, and probably ask Ondrej if there's HTTP3 support.  Note that that's still flagged as "experimental" by NGINX upstream so it might still have problems.  Lots of patches for HTTP3 in the past few weeks

Even if my original question was ‘downvoted’, it remains interesting why the module ‘--with-http_v3_module’ was compiled into Ondrej's package if only HTTP/2 is supported? Is there a reason for this that I have missed?

@ekadagami The only person who can answer that is Ondrej.  However, QUIC support is still buggy sometimes and has other issues that may take precedent so you'll still have to keep an eye on that repository.  Or compile NGINX yourself.
